# Connecting a secured websocket on Google Appengine frontend with managed VM with nodejs runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, socket.io, google-api-nodejs-client

I've trouble in connecting to a wss secured socket server via google appengine frontend with managed VM support.

buy default google exposes only port 8080 in docker image google/nodejs-runtime, Even if expose port 8443 in Dockerfile like below i can connect only to `http://localhost:8080 not https://localhost:8443`

FROM google/nodejs

WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json /app/

RUN npm install

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 8443

CMD []

ENTRYPOINT ["/nodejs/bin/npm", "start"]

Still i can see port 8080 include in the container 
 "/nodejs/bin/npm start           8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp

If i log in to my managed vm instance and run the container image with

**docker run -d -p 8443:8443 nodejs.default.wss-check:latest**

and try

`$curl https://localhost:8443`

I get curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate, It looks like its connecting but i've to use realdomain name

I've created a issue in github aswell `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-nodejs-quickstart/issues/13`, but not that helpful.

Same set up works like a charm in normal compute instance. but it doesn't auto scale. 
Any help on this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm try run and socket to on the Gae, but its a big headache! The websocket run, but I don't get the connection :(

Comment: Are you running the `curl https://localhost:8443` command *on the VM*? 

Also, have you tried googling the curl error? It sounds like you need to configure the CA's that your box is aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't curl to `https` on localhost (`curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`) is because "localhost" is unknown to any CA. You need to run `curl -k https://localhost:8443` to get it to ignore the lack of a certificate for `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick , if I don't use `-k` for localhost or if I don't give a `--cacert` parameter I encounter a warning `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unabl...` However, if I try `https://api.twitter.com` I don't have to give a `--cacert` even localhost `-k` parameter. Do you know how is this happening?

Comment: You'll need to look into how HTTPS works, and therefore how SSL/TLS works, along with certificates and "certificate authorities". There are criticisms of the CA structure, but in general they're a reliable way for sites to authenticate themselves (prove their identity), to help prevent MITM attacks. Your localhost is not set up to serve a certificate signed by a root CA, and ultimately even if you had one, you'd need to serve it from a domain name, unless you deliberately created a certificate for "localhost" (I'm not sure if you could use subjectAltNames to add the localhost name...)

Comment: This is a complex topic, but the basics of it are definitely open to be learned about, and I encourage you to look up some tutorials, guides, or youtube videos to understand HTTPS / SSL / TLS / certificates better.

Comment: You can grab the certificate from twitter to see what they have (and your localhost lacks in order to serve HTTPS) by running: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect api.twitter.com:443 </dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like currently Google Managed VM supports Websocket connection only on [JAVA](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/sdk)

Even if you try websocket connection on with nodejs on GMV it defaults to polling transport. if you wanna see this in live you can use set socket transports, deploy to live and look in to console- network and see which transport its using!

```
socket.set('transports', [
'websocket'
, 'flashsocket'
, 'htmlfile'
, 'xhr-polling'
, 'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

We have to wait untill google implements websocket support in Managed VM. If anyone get this working on GMV, Please comment here :)